# SImple css changes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a sidebar smooth transition when click so the content wrapper also makes a transiction to the left.

I simply cant do it.

```js
var rightSidebarOpen = false;
    $('#toggle-right-sidebar').click(function () {
        if(rightSidebarOpen) {
            $('#sidebar-right').hide()
            $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "0");
        }
        else {
            $('#sidebar-right').show();
            $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "205px");
        }
        rightSidebarOpen = !rightSidebarOpen;
    });
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 205px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: green;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: left 1s ease;
    display: none;
    background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="toggle-right-sidebar">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="sidebar-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something you looking for:

I set `position: relative` to `#sidebar-right` and just use `right` with the same pixel to make this move with `.content-wrapper`

```js
var rightSidebarOpen = false;
    $('#toggle-right-sidebar').click(function () {
        if(rightSidebarOpen) {
            $('#sidebar-right').css('right', "-205px");
            $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "0");
        }
        else {
            $('#sidebar-right').css('right', "0");
            $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "205px");
        }
        rightSidebarOpen = !rightSidebarOpen;
    });
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 205px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="toggle-right-sidebar">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="sidebar-right"></div>
```

Comment: perfect :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: can u explain a little bit?

Comment: I set `position: relative` to `sidebar-right` and just use `right` to make this move with `content-wrapper`

Comment: `position: relative` can set `top right botttom left` the same with absolute :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd just do the `transition` of the `right` property:

```js
var rightSidebarOpen;

$('#toggle-right-sidebar').click(function () {
  if (rightSidebarOpen) {
    //$('#sidebar-right').hide();
    $('#sidebar-right').css('right', "-200px");
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "0");
  }
  else {
    //$('#sidebar-right').show();
    $('#sidebar-right').css('right', "0");
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "205px");
  }
  rightSidebarOpen = !rightSidebarOpen;
});
```

```css
/* added */
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin: 0; overflow: hidden}

.content-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 205px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  transition: margin-right 1s; /* modified */
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: green;
}

#sidebar-right {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px; /* modified */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: right 1s; /* modified */
  /*display: none; better to put it off screen with the "right" property*/
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle-right-sidebar">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="sidebar-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

show(), hide() functions only work as display:block; and display:none; and hence you cant animate them.

HTML

```
<button id="toggle-right-sidebar">BUTTON</button>
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="sidebar-right"></div>
```

CSS

```
.content-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 205px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: green;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: translateX(200px);
    background: blue;
}
```

JS

```
var rightSidebarOpen = false;
$('#toggle-right-sidebar').click(function () {
    if(rightSidebarOpen) {
        $('#sidebar-right').css('transform', 'translateX(200px)')
        $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "0");
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar-right').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
        $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "205px");
    }
    rightSidebarOpen = !rightSidebarOpen;
});
```

You can try out this [pen](https://codepen.io/abhayincreasingly/pen/qYdNGe)